# Using find command on windows

Tags: microsoft-windows

I'm running GNU Emacs on Windows 7 and was just wondering how to set up emacs so the "find-name-dired" command works. When I try using find-name-dired to recursively search for files I get this:

```
find . "(" -iname "*.tex" ")" -exec ls -ld {} ";"
File not found - "*.tex"  
find exited abnormally with code 2 at Thu Feb 26 16:58:31
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure `find` is part of the `GNU findutils`, which is generally runs on GNU systems (i.e. not Windows). You may need to look into Cygwin/MSYS.

Comment: I have added cygwin to the beginning of my path and I still get this error.

Comment: When using GNU’s find program on Windows should be favored using executable-find% to checkout GNU’s find over Windows builtin find program. See https://github.com/junjiemars/.emacs.d/blob/master/config/on-grep-autoload.el

Answer (score 8):

I'll add this solution here as modifying the PATH can have unwanted side effects elsewhere. To set the find program to the wanted find.exe, for example provided by git:

```
(setq find-program "c:/Git/usr/bin/find.exe")
```

Comment: I needed to do `(setq find-program "C:\\Users\\rnwol\\scoop\\shims\\find.exe")`

Answer (score 3):

Emacs relies on various Unix tools, including `find`. On Windows you can install a Unix-style shell such as Cygwin, or just install ports of the specific tools you need. There are several options - I'm currently using tools from [ezwinports](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/).

Whatever you choose, you'll need to make sure that the Unix `find` command is on the path ahead of Windows one. You can do that with environment variables before starting emacs, or add to the emacs `exec-path`.

Comment: If your Git's `find.exe` is in the Program Files folder, the space in the command name can confuse emacs / Windows -- for me, doing `(setq find-program "\"C:\\Program Files\\Git\\usr\\bin\\find.exe\"")` works. (The key bit seemed to be getting the double quote characters passed down.)