# How to use Emacs on MS Windows for UNIX-like commands?

Tags: microsoft-windows, linux, cygwin, find-dired

I tried running `find-name-dired` from one of my dired buffers. I got this:

```
find . "(" -iname "*.cc" ")" -exec ls -ld {} ";"
  File not found - "*.cc"
  find exited abnormally with code 2 at Fri Feb 23 23:28:07
```

I'm running on Windows 11, `emacs-version`: GNU Emacs 29.1 (build 2, x86_64-w64-mingw32) of 2023-08-02.

I see a question about this [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9625/using-find-command-on-windows), but the answers don't work for me. I do have Git installed so I tried the recommendation:

```
(setq find-program "\"c:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/find.exe\"")
```

But then I just get an error about a missing `ls`.

```
  "c:/Program Files/Git/usr/bin/find.exe" . "(" -iname "*.cc" ")" -exec ls -ld {} ";"
  /usr/bin/find: 'ls': No such file or directory
  /usr/bin/find: 'ls': No such file or directory
  ...
```

It seems strange to me that I downloaded an Emacs build for Windows, but commands are assuming I'm on a Unix system. Am I supposed to install Cygwin? Or do people running Windows have other ways to get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing [EZWinPorts](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/efaq-w32/EZWinPorts.html)

> The EZWinPorts project provides many useful ports of recent versions of GNU and Unix software. This includes all the optional libraries used by Emacs (image libraries, *libxml2*, *GnuTLS*), *RCS*, *Texinfo*, a clone of *man* command, *Grep*, *xz*, *bzip2*, *bsdtar*, *ID Utils*, *Findutils*, *Hunspell*, *Gawk*, *GNU Make*, *Groff*, *GDB*.

From the project page https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/

> This project is a collection of ports to MS-Windows of GNU and Unix software packages, which either don't have precompiled Windows binaries available, or whose existing ports are buggy or broken.

> All the ports are built using the MinGW development environment, with or without MSYS.

The project is maintained by Eli Zaretskii, the current Emacs mainainer.

Comment: BTW, is there any scripts to download all the ports? Or we can only download them one by one manually.

Comment: Always start with [`README.txt`]( https://sourceforge.net/projects/ezwinports/files/README.txt/download) and it answers your question