# use `ripgrep` for everything that `grep` would be used for on Windows

Tags: grep, project, ripgrep

Given that `grep` is not available on windows, I'm trying to use `ripgrep` as a drop-in replacement so that I can use things like `project-find-regexp`.

I don't need any extra functionality, just that anything emacs does that would use `grep` instead uses `ripgrep`. I've tried following this blog post https://stegosaurusdormant.com/emacs-ripgrep/, to plug it in, but it still tries to use the original `grep`

Is there a way to just drop in `ripgrep` for `grep` so that `project-find-regexp` works?

Comment: `grep` is available as part of Ezwinports https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/80495/42623

Comment: Thanks @mxnt, this did help, but I found that ezwinports was not so ez to install. This did however prompt me to find GnuWin32 which while older, was very simple to install with `winget`. I'd still like to find a way to use `ripgrep` as a drop-in replacement since it is so much faster, but this at least has me working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest solution that I was able to find to make `project-find-regexp` "just work" on windows was to use the `winget` package manager that comes with window to install the GnuWin32 version of grep

```
winget install GnuWin32.grep
```

followed by the following to install `xargs` (which is used by project-find-regexp)

```
winget install GnuWin32.FindUtils
```